# How do I pass type in c# methods?

Tags: c#, methods, types, parameter-passing

I want to write a method which searches for an object in my list, which can contain multiple inherited types.

```
public class MyClass 
{
   public readonly List<parentType> objects = new List<parentType>();

   public parentType GetObject(Type type, string tag)
   {
       foreach (parentType _object in objects)
       {
           if (_object.GetType() == type)
           {
                if (tag == _object.tag)
                {
                    return _object;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

But when I call *.GetObject(childType, "tag")* I get CS0119: *'childType' is a type, which is not valid in the given context*.

What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: `.GetObject(typeof(childType), "tag")` ?

Comment: Do you know exact `childType` in compile time or you should get it in runtime from some data?

Comment: @YongShun thanks, that solved my problem. As you can see I'm still new to c# so sorry for bothering you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several possibilities here:

- use `typeof` - `GetObject(typeof(childType), "tag")`
- rewrite your function in generic way and use type as generic parameter

  ```
  public parentType GetObject<T>(string tag) where T: parentType
  {
    //use T as the type to search
  }
  ```

  and then call it `GetObject<childType>("tag");`

  In some cases it may be also usefull to use generic parameter to return more concrete type

  ```
  T GetObject<T>(string tag) where T: parentType
  {
  }
  ```

  Moreover (but a little offtopic) you can use LINQ to get more simple and idiomatic solution

  ```
  public T GetObject<T>(string tag) where T: parentType
  {
    return objects.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.tag == tag);
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you, that really helped :). Does the linq option still return null when it can't find the object in the list?

Comment: Yes, it does. LINQ `FirstOrDefault` will return `default(T)` if nothing found or if collection is empty. In your case (as the `parentType` is a class or other reference type), it will return `null` when nothing found, as the default value of reference type is `null`.